# How to include a script tag only if an element exists?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This seems like something that should be straightforward but I'm a newbie with Javascript, so please be patient.

I want to include a script file but only if an element exists on the page.  I've tried:

```
var element = $('.customelement');

if(element.length() > 0) {
  $('head').append('<script language="javascript" src="custom.js"></script>');
}
```

But this doesn't work and returns the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Property 'length' of object [object Object] is
>   not a function

I have found many posts which say this should work so I'm a little stumped.  I was also wondering if there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By `length()`, I believe you meant `length` (It's a Javascript property, not a jQuery function):

```
if(element.length > 0) {
  $('head').append('<script language="javascript" src="custom.js"></script>');
}
```

Comment: @Deepu, please don't attempt to vandalize a good answer by introducing bad grammar and incorrect edits.

Comment: Thank you.  I am still learning the difference and waiting for the aha moment to occur.

Answer (score 2):

As the error message states, `length` is a property but not a function:

```
if (element.length > 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what the error says. `length` is a property, not a function. Remove the `()`.